# How to launch generator without loading models through observers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, rails-engines, observers

Given an engine and an application, I have an engine generator that creates yaml settings file for my application.
A part of these settings are used to define some model validation.
Everything was fine until I added (and registered) an observer to my model.

Now when I call any generator on a fresh application, my model is loaded by the observer.
So it gives me an error on model validation because it expects to read a not yet created yaml file.

I looked for a solution to disable observers when I launch my generator but I didn't find anything.

Is there a way to fix this issue?